# Using state to navigate to another React component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-state-management

I have a simple React app for displaying games.

It has 3 buttons across the top of the page that control where the user can go when clicked like this:

```
[Games]   |   [Create]    |    [Login]
```

For my GamesList.js, CreateGame.js, and LoginForm.js components.

The navigation is simply controlled with React hooks like this:

```
// *** GamerPagesNavigation.js

const [showGames, setGames] = useState(true);
const [showCreate, setCreate] = useState(false);
const [showLogin, setLogin] = useState(false);


const handleGamesClick = useCallback(e => { (setCreate(false) || setLogin(false) ) || setGames(true) });
const handleCreateClick = useCallback(e => { (setGames(false) || setLogin(false) ) || setCreate(true) });
const handleLoginClick = useCallback(e => { (setCreate(false) || setGames(false) ) || setLogin(true) });

<div>
    {showGames && <GamesList />}
</div>
<div>
    {showCreate && <CreateGame />}
</div>
<div>
    {showLogin && <LoginForm />}
</div>
```

And it works wonderfully! :)

So that works great!

But now, I have a button on my LoginForm.js component for logging in.

When submitted and authenticated, I want the user to be directed to the Login page.

But I can't figure out how to go from the LoginForm.js component to the CreateGame component.

Because my state is controlled in the GamerPagesNavigation.js component, I can't figure out how to get the state values in another component.

When I tried this in my LoginForm.js component, it said showCreate is undefined:

```
setCreate(true)
```

Which I get, because it's defined in a different React component file.

So is there a way to do this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the function via props

```
    <LoginForm onLogin={() => setCreate(true)} />
```

From LoginForm.js

call `props.onLogin()` when needed

Comment: But in the LoginForm.js component, when I click on the submit button, I want the screen to goto the CreateGame.js component...would this work?  thanks!

Comment: Sure, if your idea is to centralize the navigation into one component, then child components should call it's parents via callbacks, this way the state is only being stored into the navigation component. Although I would recommend you to use a React navigation library like "react router" or "reach router". Which would also give you nice looking URLs in your App.

Comment: Ok I did that.  I but the onLogin{() => handleLoginClick()} part in my GamerPagesNavigation.js component. Then I put props.onLogin() in my const LoginForm = (props) => { } part.  But nothing happens.  is props.onLogin() supposed to do something?  I'm not familiar with it.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I think I wasn't understanding completely what you wanted to do here. So you basically want to run setCreate() from within a child. I will update my answer.

Comment: By calling a parent function via callback, the function is actually being executed within the context of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const [showGames, setGames] = useState(true);
const [showCreate, setCreate] = useState(false);
const [showLogin, setLogin] = useState(false);


const handleGamesClick = useCallback(e => { (setCreate(false) || setLogin(false) ) || setGames(true) });
const handleCreateClick = useCallback(e => { (setGames(false) || setLogin(false) ) || setCreate(true) });
const handleLoginClick = useCallback(e => { (setCreate(false) || setGames(false) ) || setLogin(true) });

<div>
    {showGames && <GamesList />}
</div>
<div>
    {showCreate && <CreateGame />}
</div>
<div>
    {showLogin && <LoginForm handleCreateClick={handleCreateClick}/>}
</div>
```

then inside LoginForm destructure it

```
const LoginForm = (props)=>{
 const {handleCreateClick}= props;
 const handleSubmit=()=>{
 // your form submission logic
 handleCreateClick()
}
return(
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
//your form inputs 
</form>
)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so I did all that like you suggested but I get this error: "handleCreateClick is not a function"